# What is bash in c?

Tags: bash

I am taking my very first programming class, and it is an online course. I have written a program to cipher the alphabet and it has no issues (that the computer caught). In my command line I keep getting this

```
Usage: ./asciimath 
keyjharvard@appliance (~/Dropbox/pset2): A
bash: A: command not found
```

I have no the slightest clue what this means and google hasn't helped.

Comment: [Google provides a whole page full of helpful resources when I try it.](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash) What do you see?

Comment: You haven't actually provided enough detail.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. But thank you!!

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, what exactly did you figure out? Incidentally, I edited your question to fix the formatting, but it still doesn't look right; that looks like a shell prompt in the middle of a usage message.

Answer (score 3):

"bash" is a Linux command shell.

I think that the correct way to parse that message is as follows:

```
bash: A: command not found
```

Your course-ware (the "./asciimath" thing?) has tried to execute a command called "A" using the shell, and the shell has said that it cannot find a command called 'A'.

At this point, you need to talk to support folks for the online course ... or reread the instructions.  It is not clear from the context whether there is something broken with the course-ware, you are doing something incorrect ... or both.